# ANTLR Grammar - Error parsing script block

Tags: java, antlr, grammar

I'm trying to create a grammar in ANTLR, which is depicted bellow.

```
grammar EPL2;

standard_rule:
          'STANDARD' 'RULE' ':'
          'FILTER' SCRIPT
          'SINK' SCRIPT;

SCRIPT
 : '{' SCRIPT_ATOM* '}'
  ;


 fragment SCRIPT_ATOM
   : ~[{}]
   | '"' ( ~('"') )* '"'
   | '//' ~[\r\n]*
   | SCRIPT
   ;

 MultiLineComment
  : '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN)
  ;

 SingleLineComment
  : '//' ~[\r\n\u2028\u2029]* -> channel(HIDDEN)
  ;

 SPACES
  : [ \u000B\t\r\n] -> channel(HIDDEN)
  ;
```

When I run the grammar against the following input:

```
STANDARD RULE:
FILTER { data.get("abc") == "a"; }
SINK { data.get("xyz") > 10 ;}
```

I get this error:
**line 3:36 mismatched input '' expecting 'SINK'**

I'm using a IntelliJ plugin to visualize the parse tree and hierarchy. I can see that the second SCRIPT is getting attached to the first as illustrated by the following figure.

[image: Hierarchy]

When I close the bracket (}) the parser should advance to the sink clause but this isn't happening.

If I add an open or closing bracket to the second String ("{a") the scond
script appears correctly.

[image]

I don't know what am I doing wrong, any clues?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I've read the explanation but I didn't understand how does that case applies here. Even if I change the order (SPACES declaration first) the problem persists. Can you elaborate a bit more? thank you.

Comment: Hmm yes sorry I think I've reacted too early without thinking it through, so I've removed my previous comment. `SCRIPT_ATOM` must have matched the part between the two blocks, but it's unclear to me how it managed to do so (and `SPACES` should almost always be last anyway, that's not your issue). You may try the following: replace `~[{}]` with `~[{}"]` and put it as the *last* alternative in the fragment (I don't remember if the order matters in lexer rules). You may also try to use a nongreedy quantifier: `SCRIPT_ATOM*?`, but as I said, I'm not sure how it got to that point so I speculate :/

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, non-greedy will not work, I think, because `SCRIPT_ATOM` can contain other atoms. (I might be wrong, admittedly).